# What is the number of ordered triplets of natural numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a b c=2^5 \times 3^7$ and H.C.F. $(a, b, c)=1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, combinations, gcd-and-lcm

**Question :**
What is the number of ordered triplets of natural numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a b c=2^5 \times 3^7$ and H.C.F. $(a, b, c)=1$

**My approach :**
I tried making cases where the exponent of $2$ is "shared" between two numbers and the last one is $3^7$, then I did the same the other way round, then one having 2, one with 3, and one with both.
It was really tedious and I got the wrong answer $180$ [ and the text book itself had the wrong answer $432$ ] whereas the right answer is $315$.

Comment: What is H.C.F.?

Comment: Its gcd @gnasher729 highest common factor if I remember right

Comment: According to my calculations , it should be [ $15 \times 21 = 315$ ] though I looked & checked & re-checked & re-re-checked it ! I will delete that Post now , though some thing is weird some where !

Comment: I think you should check the answers now , grimm , to rectify the "accepted" mark here. The currently "accepted" answer is clearly wrong !

Comment: @RandomGuy Thanks. I’ve never ever heard it called that. Only gcd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PROBLEM :

Let us say we have $3$ "Buckets" where we want to "Distribute" $5$ "Black" Balls & $7$ "White" Balls.
Let us also say that all $3$ Buckets having a Common Colour Ball is not allowed.

It is "almost" Equivalent to what you want.

### CALCULATION :

Total ways of Distributing $5$ Black Balls : Partitioning $5$ into $3$ Parts.
There is a formula to get that , though we can avoid that formula in this simple case.
We can see that :
$(0,a,5-a)$ will work for $a=0,\cdots,5$ : 6 ways
$(1,a,4-a)$ will work for $a=0,\cdots,4$ : 5 ways
$(2,a,3-a)$ will work for $a=0,\cdots,3$ : 4 ways
$(3,a,2-a)$ will work for $a=0,\cdots,2$ : 3 ways
$(4,a,1-a)$ will work for $a=0,\cdots,1$ : 2 ways
$(5,a,0-a)$ will work for $a=0,\cdots,0$ : 1 ways
Total $6 \times 7/2 = 21$ ways

Like-wise for the White Balls , we have $8 \times 9/2 = 36$

Total ways $21 \times 36 = 756$
It is "almost" Equivalent to the Number Case.

We are over-counting the Cases where Common Colour Ball might occur in all Buckets. We want to eliminate that.

Put $1$ Black Ball each in the $3$ Buckets.
We have $2$ Balls , which we can "Partition" like $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ : $3 \times 4/2 = 6$ Ways are not "allowed".
Hence $21-6 = 15$ ways are "allowed".

Like-wise for White Balls , put $1$ White Ball each in the $3$ Buckets.
We have $4$ Balls , which gives $5 \times 6/2 = 15$ ways which are not allowed.
Hence "allowed" ways are $36-15 = 21$
Hence the total ways we want is $15 \times 21 = 315$

### SUMMARY :

Total ways (with or without Common Coluor Ball) is $756$
Total ways without Common Colour Ball is $315$ (this is what we want)
$756-315=441$ ways are not allowed due to Common Colour Ball.

### ADDENDUM :

I changed my line of attack : Instead of checking what was wrong here , I decided to list the various ways & figure out what was wrong with the other answer. That will show what is wrong where. I was able to figure the Core Issue !

Here are the $6$ ways to Distribute the $5$ Black Balls in 2 Buckets , leaving the first Bucket Empty :
$\color{red}{(0,0,5)},(0,1,4),(0,2,3),(0,3,2),(0,4,1),\color{red}{(0,5,0)}$
Now , the other answer multiplies this by $3$ to get $3 \times 6 = 18$ , because the Empty Bucket can be the middle or the last.
$\color{red}{(0,0,5)},(1,0,4),(2,0,3),(3,0,2),(4,0,1),\color{red}{(5,0,0)}$
$\color{red}{(0,5,0)},(1,4,0),(2,3,0),(3,2,0),(4,1,0),\color{red}{(5,0,0)}$

We can easily see that the first & the last (in red) will be over-counted $6$ times , though it should be counted only $3$ times , excluding the repeated elements.
Thus is it only $15$ ways.

Similarly , the other answer over-counts by $3$ to get $24$ , rather than $21$.

Hence Correct total is not $18 \times 24 = 432$ , it is $15 \times 21 = 315$
The other Answer is wrong , even though it is accepted.

WHEW !!

Comment: The answer is 432, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the update , @Grimm , Both Answers can not be right ! Since this is the wrong Answer , I will check where I went wrong , or I will Delete this Post !

Comment: Answer is $315$ , @Grimm , not $432$ , you should re-check it

Comment: I guess you were right after all. I was pretty biased towards 432 being the answer because my book has it in the answer key but apparantly it is wrong. Thank you for your continuous effort.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you have put a lot of effort into solving it and proving that 432 was not the answer. But, I am going to be honest, user's method is far better.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the text book itself had a typo or wrong entry. No issues with me being right or wrong , which occurs all the time. I just like to figure out where I go wrong to rectify myself. Thank you for your feedback. There are shorter ways , through the use of the formula which I mentioned. I avoided it to high-light the actual calculations behind the formula !

Comment: Ah fudge I'm sorry I'll look through mine again Edit: OK I think I figured it out the pick two then dist method prolly gives a metric ton of repeats

Comment: No worries , the repeats are the red entries in my ADDENDUM Part , @RandomGuy , where Exchanging $0$ Elements in the triplets will count twice. There are $3$ times this occurs hence $18-3=15$ & $24-3=21$ !

Answer (score 2):

Pick two to share 2 then 5 identical balls 2 distinct boxes
$$
{}^3 \mathrm{C}_2 {}^{5+2-1} \mathrm{C}_{2-1}=18
$$

Now we do the same for 3
$$
{}^3 \mathrm{C}_2 {}^{7+2-1} \mathrm{C}_{2-1}=24
$$

So the total required is $18×24=432$

The error with your solution is that you assumed only the last number could have 3

Answer (score 2):

The answer $432$ is not correct. The correct answer $315$ was given by Perm but later deleted because of unclear reasons. I will repeat here his arguments.

The problem is equivalent to the problem of distributing $5$ black balls and $7$ white balls between three bins, provided that balls of the same color cannot be put in all three bins.

Without the latter restriction the balls can be distributed in
$$
\binom{5+2}{2}=21\quad\text{and}\quad\binom{7+2}{2}=36
$$
ways, respectively (see [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))).

From this we should subtract the number of cases where all three bins contain at least one ball of the given color. To find the number we place one ball of the color in each bin and count the number of ways to distribute the rest ($2$ and $4$, respectively) balls between the bins. One obtains:
$$
\binom{2+2}{2}=6\quad\text{and}\quad\binom{4+2}{2}=15
$$
such distributions, respectively, so that the final answer to your question is:
$$
(21-6)\times(36-15)=15\times21=315.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check , user "user" , I deleted it because OP said I was wrong. I went away from the Issue to think about what was wrong & then I could figure the over-counting in the other wrong answer. When I came back to undelete with my "Proof" of Correctness , I was pleasantly surprised to see that you confirmed it too !

Comment: It is nice that you undeleted your answer, but I will not now delete mine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here , hence nothing to delete ! I can only upvote ! Let this alternate shorter informative way be available here !

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also be treated well with *PIE* the *[principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*.
This answer contains a fairly detailed explanation. If you are familiar with PIE, you might only want to look at the section marked with the bar.

> We consider a set $E$ of properties
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{E=\{e_1,e_2\}}
> \end{align*}
> Here
>
> - $\color{blue}{e_1}$ is the property, that $2$ is a common factor of $a,b$ and $c$, i.e. $\color{blue}{2|\gcd(a,b,c)}$
> - $\color{blue}{e_2}$ is the property, that $3$ is a common factor of $a,b$ and $c$, i.e. $\color{blue}{3|\gcd(a,b,c)}$.
>
> We define for sets $T\subseteq E$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N_{\supseteq T}}
> &=\#\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3:abc=2^53^7,
> \gcd(a,b,c) \mathrm{\ possesses\ }\bf{at\ least}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\mathrm{\ the\ factors\ according\ to\ properties\ }\ e_j\mathrm{\ in\ }\it{T}\}\\
> \color{blue}{N_{= T}}
> &=\#\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3:abc=2^53^7,
> \gcd(a,b,c) \mathrm{\ possesses\ }\bf{exactly}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\mathrm{\ the\ factors\ according\ to\ properties\ }\ e_j\mathrm{\ in\ }\it{T}\}\\
> \end{align*}

Since we are looking for the numbers of triples $(a,b,c)$ with $abc=2^53^7$ with
\begin{align*}
\gcd(a,b,c)=1
\end{align*}
we want to calculate $\color{blue}{N_{=\emptyset}}$ which means that neither $2$ nor $3$ is a divisor of $\gcd(a,b,c)$ and consequently $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

> According to PIE we calculate
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N_{=\emptyset}}
> &\color{blue}{=N_{\supseteq\emptyset}-N_{\supseteq \{e_1\}}-N_{\supseteq \{e_2\}}+N_{\supseteq \{e_1,e_2\}}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{7}{2}\binom{9}{2}-\binom{4}{2}\binom{9}{2}
> -\binom{7}{2}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\tag{2}\\
> &=21\cdot 36-6\cdot 36-21\cdot 15+6\cdot 15\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=315}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use PIE and calculate $N_{=\emptyset}$ the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ with $abc=2^53^7$ and $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ as

  - $\color{blue}{N_{\supseteq\emptyset}:}$ the number of *all* triples $(a,b,c)$ with $abc=2^53^7$
  - $\color{blue}{-N_{\supseteq \{e_1\}}:}$ minus the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ which have the factor $2$ (or more factors) dividing $\gcd(a,b,c)$
  - $\color{blue}{-N_{\supseteq \{e_2\}}:}$ minus the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ which have the factor $3$ (or more factors) dividing $\gcd(a,b,c)$
  - $\color{blue}{+ N_{\supseteq \{e1,e_2\}}:}$ plus the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ which have the factor $2$ and $3$ dividing $\gcd(a,b,c)$, which is a compensation for subtracting these numbers twice when calculating $-N_{\supseteq \{e_1\}}-N_{\supseteq \{e_2\}}$.
- In (2) we use *[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_proof)* to calculate the numbers $N_{\supseteq T}$ with $T\subseteq E$ from the right-hand side of (1). Let's for instance have a closer look at
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{N_{\supseteq \{e_1\}}}
  \end{align*}
  We consider $abc=2^53^7$ where according to property $e_1$ we have that $2|\gcd(a,b,c)$. This implies we have $2|a, 2|b$ and $2|c$ and there are two factors $2$ left and seven factors $3$ left for distributing them with zero or more factors to $a, b$ and $c$ respectively.

  - Two factors $2$ distributed to three variables $a,b$ and $c$ gives $\binom{2+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{4}{2}$
  - Seven factors $3$ distributed to three variables $a,b,$ and $c$ gives $\binom{3+7-1}{7-1}=\binom{6}{2}$
  - Since these two distributions do not depend on each other the total number is $\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}$.

  The calculation of the other numbers $N_{\supseteq\emptyset}, N_{\supseteq \{e_2\}}$ and $N_{\supseteq \{e_1,e_2\}}$ follows accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The gcd(a,b,c) is 1, so one is not divisible by 2, and one is not divisible by 3. There are 15 ways to distribute the powers of 2, 21 ways to distribute the powers of 3, so the total is 315.

(The 15 are 0,n,5-n for 1 <= n <= 4, times 3 because each of a,b,c can be 0, and 0,0,5 times 3).